# Install graphic driver for AMD Ryzen 7 5800U APU

Tags: drivers, graphics, brightness, amd-ryzen

I have brand new HP Zhan (hp probook 445 g8) with AMD Ryzen 5800u.
The screen brightness is not adjustable, the HDMI and USB-C ports doesn't work. I can't connect to external displays.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

`5.8.0-45-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 23 13:46:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I tried to install kernel 5.11.6 but the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW, after install the kernel 5.11.7 and latest linux-firmware 1.187.10 but the it doesn't solve the problem. I google something and found this post: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=336958
Then I tried to comment out the `blacklist amdgpu` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf` then run the command `sudo modprobe amdgpu`.
BOOM, it works. Now I can change the screen brightness, HDMI port works. AWESOME.